# How to mutate `ui.Image` in Flutter, or draw frequently mutated image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a roughly 1000x1000 image, which will be mutated at 60fps, each time changing color of only dozens of pixels.

Then, I need to display this image in Flutter. Of course I can use `Image.memory(the_uint8list_data)`, but it will be extremely costly since it will create 60 new big images in one second. I have also checked `ui.Image`, but it is opaque and I do not see any handles to change pixel data. I originally used `Path`-based solutions, but that was also too slow because the mutation can happen for a long time and the Path will be very huge.

The question is, how can I display this image with high performance?

Comment: If you want to change only dozen of pixels it would be easier to draw them inside `CustomPainter`

Comment: @pskink But they accumulate... So after, say, 100fps, there are 100x dozens of pixels.

Comment: check `PictureRecorder` - after some X frames you can convert it to `Picture` and then to `Image` that you can draw directly with `CustomPainter`